# Как учить ребенка программировать?

Tags: алгоритм

**Дано:** оболтус 10 лет с уверенными навыками пользования всеми доступными гаджетами, устройствами, компами и проч.

Требуется: научить программировать

Вопрос Как это сделать, с чего начать?

Comment: Мой (11 лет) прочитал сам только "Маленького принца". Впихнула в него Робинзона, а с Таинственным островом уже не совладал. Хотя техническую литературу "глотает" моментально... Жаль, но свои мозги не пришьешь. Пусть хоть не приучается в игрушкам...

Comment: Ну робинзона с островами и мушкетерами мы уже прочитали...

Comment: У меня самостоятельно проснулся интерес к программированию в 11 лет, первый компьютер собрал себе в 8. Помнится сначала я нашел у кого-то компилятор Turbo Pascal 7.0 с парой примеров, а потом нашел где-то на "толкучке" здоровенный толмут по паскалю. Потом пошли С/С++, PHP, Python и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: имхо, не надо такое делать =) может ему лучше скрипку купить? =) жди пока он сам подойдет и спросит "че ты делаешЬ? и как это у тебя получается?"

Comment: @Gorets у меня есть гитара, но оболтус так ни разу и не подошел и не спросил что это такое и как у тебя это получается

Comment: понимаешь, жзнь такая непростая штука, что исправить "ошибки" и сделать все как ты представляешь в идеале не всегда получится, особенно на своих детях... поначалу кажется, что "если бы у меня были родители программисты, если бы я жил в штатах... в богатой семье... если бы меня заставили программировать с 5 лет... я бы был сейчас...." - все это на самом деле фигня, потому что если бы не все эти "если" жизнь не была бы такой классной, потому лучше поддерживать его в том что эту нравиться сейчас.. рисовать или мультики на компе делать.. или что-то другое

Comment: ну и остальное при желании догонится.. например, я в 8 классе боялся английского и думал, что выучить его нереально... но в институте так поперло, что теперь я не представляю, что там может быть непонятного, если это достаточно логический и простой язык... ну и с химией я не дружил, но при желании в 10 классе, взял книги с 8 до 11 и за месяц догнал всю программу

Comment: мне почему-то кажется что если насильно навязывать ему что-то то он сначала будет упиратся, потом делать все для того чтоб от него отстали, а если и начнет изучать программирование то не будет проявлять к нему интерес. 
думаю лучше всего устроить "замануху", - показывать какие-то прикольные програмки чтоб его заинтересовать :) 
после этого можно дать какой-то простенький язык высокого уровня, когда немного разберется тогда уже алгоритмы, архитектуру, ...

Comment: update: совсем забыл, есть игрушки в которых можно программировать роботов, - ребенку будет интересно а кроме того можно будет освоить азы алгоритмов и программирования. у меня была одна такая правда небыло времени =/ кажется "colobot", а в прочем по запросу "игры программирование роботов" гугль выдает много результатов

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/142898/

Comment: О_о У программистов есть дети?

Comment: И даже, что еще хуже, у не-программистов. Как мне научить сына, имея только навык Паскаля, самостоятельно изучавшегося 20 лет назад?

Comment: Вот чтобы столько ответов и комментов было на нормальные вопросы, у которых 0 ответов месяцами, а потом уже холивары разводили об обучении ребёнка!!! ИМХО.

Comment: @megacoder, яростно плюсую. Надо срочно делать metahashcode и отделять говорильню. Как глянешь на список самых популярных вопросов, так аж грустно делается.

Comment: @Olter, @megacoder, правильно. Только должна быть возможность легко делать ссылки между темами в разных частях.

Comment: Люто, бешено плюсую, как размножаются настоящие программисты науке не известно ;-) @neofit, а что, Паскаль - отличный базис для понимания алгоритмических ЯП.

Comment: Да, но ничего другого я не знаю. Сейчас, правда, изучаю статистический язык R. Главное - иметь банк задач, достаточно интересных для такого возраста. Может, открыть такую тему здесь?

Comment: @neofit Изучать вместе с ребёнком. Тем более о перспективности R (я его абсолютно не знаю) много пишут. Дитё может ещё сильно удивить папу. @karmadro4 а что такое неалгоритмический ЯП?

Comment: @alexlz, вообще-то маму (т.е. меня). Дала ему задачи, которые подготовила для студентов.

Comment: @megacoder, в чем проблема? Просто дети - это жизнь! Не заходите в эту тему и все. Конечно, здесь многовато банальностей, типа "надо книжки читать и в футбол играть" - это и так все знают.

Comment: @alexlz, [определение из словаря](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA). @neofit, позвольте! Это - открытый (ну... почти) форум, где каждый имеет право высказать мнение, не надо "прогонять". Зайдите лучше в справку и почитайте, почему данный чатик не подходит по формату.

Comment: важно: а ка у него с математикой, логикой?

Comment: поставь линукс без иксов.

Comment: @eicto. Правильно. И пусть на линуксе без иксов начинает обучение программированию с написания скриптов, например к blender'у! Или на какой-нибудь детской обучалке (с графикой).

Comment: Все ответы — отстой. Надо с книги SICP начинать.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Как обучали меня в школе:

**2 класс** Роботландия: перевозчик, автомат и т.п.

**3 класс** Роботландия: Кукарача — заставлять бегать и двигать буквы таракана по полю 10x10 с помощью процедурного программирования.

**5-6 класс** QBasic — простые программы: от игры «Угадайка» до простой анимации. Устройство компьютера (процессор — обрабатывает данные, оперативная память — хранит данные, устройства ввода-вывода ...).

**7-9 класс** Pascal. Системы счисления, булева логика... — то что называют "информатика" в очень сжатом виде. Вообще с седьмого класса началось обучение программированию, в том числе мы решали много олимпиадных задачек разной сложности. Структурное программирование.

**10 класс** Delphi — оконные программы от простых до сложных. Годовая работа — качественное построение графиков (с учетом разрывов как у функции `y = tg(x)`, и т.п.).

**11 класс** C. Одно из зачетных заданий — написать архиватор и разархиватор с алгоритмом Хаффмана (который, к слову, мы проверяли так: прогоняли в обе стороны `photoshop.exe`, подменяли его в папке `Program files` и запускали :-)

Параллельно в 9-11 классе вне школы (курсы в местном вузе и самостоятельно) изучал C++, немного Javascript и Python.

Ну а дальше я поступил в университет по специальности «прикладная математика и информатика».

**UPD** совсем забыл написать — это все было на фоне обучения в физмат школе.

**UPD 2** не забывайте про дополнительное образование (например, музыкальная школа, художественная, спортивная секция и т.д.) и здоровье ребенка.

Comment: Я вам завидую... Возьму на вооружение

Comment: что такое роботландия?

Comment: @Barmaley Это графическая среда для обучения школьников с логическими задачами (Перевозчик, Угадайка, Буквоед...) и так называемыми Исполнителями (Плюсик, Автомат, Кукарача). Все это было под DOS. Примерно в 2007 году видел, что уже есть версия под Windows.

Comment: Мне все здесь нравится кроме обучения Delphi - уверен, что это был целенаправленная диверсия ЦРУ (которая кстати удалась на 200%)

Comment: >2 класс Устройство компьютера (процессор, оперативная память, устройства ввода-вывода ...)
мы во втором классе кружки с квадратами складывали...

Comment: @Андрей - везучий человек. В моей школе нам компьютер показывали только в 7м классе, это был аппарат, с клавиатурой, покрытой пленкой, работающий от магнитофона. 
p.s. работать на нем не давали, только смотреть. Что такое комп первый раз узнал в универе на 1м курсе)

Comment: @teanЫЧ ну это все было на очень примитивном уровне: "Есть процессор - он обрабатывает данные, считает. Есть память - там хранятся данные."

Comment: Круто! А в 11-ом классе правда заставили архиватор писать???

Comment: у меня одного в 10-11 классах кроме офиса ничего по информатике не преподавали?

Comment: @Spectre, вы еще счастливчик у меня в школе были две массивные железные двери за которыми находился компьютерный класс, но за них никто из учеников так ни разу и не попал )

Comment: Что ж сказать... nerd:)

Хотя я Вам очень сильно завидую... начал бы я хотя бы с 8-го класса...

Comment: Блин, у меня прямо комплекс неполноценности развивается когда читаю про устройство компьютера во 2-ои классе, у меня в это время был Ленин на субботнике, рождество в доме Ульяновых и что-то про листовки (Союз уже развалился, но всем было не до переиздания учебников), комп с виндой у меня появился только в 14 лет, а интернет в 19 :( Правда, был еще советский клон IBM PC, БКшка и собранный отцом спектрум, но последние два как-то недолго

Comment: @alexlz , "советский клон IBM PC, БКшка и собранный отцом спектрум" - это перечисление трех разных устройств, клон ИБМ был типа такого http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%A1_%D0%9F%D0%AD%D0%92%D0%9C

Comment: есть вариант, что я все-таки перепутал модель и было не совсем оно, но в принципе все может быть - у меня отец и дед были военными инженерами, причем дед вроде бы был связан со всевозможной поставкой радиоэлектроники

Comment: медленно. думаю лучше попаскалить ещё в 4 классе.

Comment: Да нет, я счастлив, что у меня не было такого детства. Я в футбол играл, за гаражами курил и за девками бегал))

Comment: на мой взгляд Pascel необходим ) все знакомые кто начинал на Pascal, Delphi с легкостью схватывают любой язык программирования!, а вот начинающие с C++ далеко не уходили, и доходило до того, что они не признают других языков. на счет питоне незнаю )

Comment: @Barmaley, чем плох Делфи в качестве академического языка?

Comment: @IVsevolod А где взять Pascel? (Шютка)

     все знакомые кто начинал на Pascal, Delphi с легкостью схватывают любой язык программирования!

Брехня ((c) С.Краморов, х/ф "Неуловимые мстители")). А если серьёзно -- для некоторых языков это справедливо, для некоторых -- совсем наоборот.

@Сахарок А чем плохо обучение письму с помощью перьевых (ручки, перья "Пионер" и чернильницы-непроливайки)? Век другой, время ушло. Задачи другие.

Comment: > Т.е. старт с Pascal в таких случаях принесёт только вред.

соглашусь только, "старт с Pascal в некоторых случаях принесет только вред"

Comment: @alexlz, а все таки, чем изучение процедурного языка (к тому  же созданного для обучения) может навредить?

И какие это новые задачи не требуют традиционного алгоритмического мышления (как я понимаю Pascal разработан именно для таких задач).

Comment: @IVsevolod вопрос только когда этот результат обнаружится (чем позже, тем больше усилий придётся прикладывать для поворота мозгов).

@avp Pascal разработан для обучения программированию (так же, как ранее -- Basic). Это были славные времена ("Если человек понял, что переменная меняет своё занчение -- то он понял программирование". возможно Дейкстра). А когда это понимание укоренилось, попробуйте переучить человека на работу с переменными, которые своих значений не меняют... (имеются в виду декларативные языки программирования). sicp и htdp таких травм вроде не делают, там разные вещи изучаютс

Comment: Я бы вместо паскаля с дельфи предпочел бы питон, потому что qBasic, Pascal, Delfi- есть модульное программирование с разным синтаксисом, что не принесет существенной пользы, так как и паскаль и дельфа скоро загнутся (личное предвзятое мнение), а вот питон своей простотой, красотой и очевидностью сильно может помочь начинающему программисту.  
@alexlz, ага, а потом начинаешь изучать erlang и начинаешь удивляться как переменная не может менять свое значение.

Comment: @alexlz, я так понимаю, что  sicp и htdp  это про scheme?

Неужели в этом диалекте лиспа нет переменных (в т.ч. глобальных), которым можно присваивать разные значения?

Comment: (1) Есть и можно. Но необязательно.

(2) sicp в MIT уже вроде на python'е преподают. Вроде видел тексты программ где-то. Но сейчас не уверен.

htdp просматривал мельком, а в sicp рассматривалось и императивное, и функциональное программирование. Т.е. можно и так, и эдак. Это, по-моему, правильней, чем изучать только один стиль программирования, а потом от него мучительно отвыкать.

Comment: Ну вы загнули :) В 9 классе Basic) Да вы что :)

Answer (score 22):

Добрый день. Мне самому 12 лет, но помимо того, что я отличник , я ещё занимаюсь изучением языков программирования и web-дизайна. Я уже знаю HTML, JavaScript, Css, PHP и сейчас учу C++. В будущем планирую поступить в Высшее Учебное Заведение(вуз)на информатико- математический факультет, кафедра: навыки работы с вычислительной техникой.

Comment: Нормально. И вспоминая себя в твоём возрасте, я думаю, что постарался бы сделать примерно то же, только вот возможности не было. Таким образом получить конкретный результат ты сможешь быстрее. Но. Изучив (более или менее) данные языки (javascript, php, c++) и получив некоторый опыт работы на них, ты гарантируешь себе проблемы при изучении декларативных языков. Оно, конечно, ничего страшного, многие через это прошли. Только помни, что ты далеко не из первой тысячи (десятков тысяч, сотен), наступающих на эти грабли.

Comment: @artyom ты крут!

Comment: Благодарю Вас за этот столь полезный для меня комментарий.

Comment: молодец, так держать!

Comment: @artyom attention whore

Comment: Почему "whore" ? =)

Comment: ты крут ) посоветую тебе участвовать в олимпиадах по программированию! вот например на http://codeforces.ru/ часто проводят олимпиады.

Comment: haskell пробовал ?

Comment: Зря php, зря...

Answer (score 11):

Пусть лет до 15 лучше книжки умные читает. И в школе хорошо учится. (Если, конечно, ему самому не невтерпеж).

Comment: Поздновато не будет? Времена то ведь уже не те... Это мы начинали после 15-ти

Comment: во... mikillskegg, почти тоже самое, что я говорю... времена не те? может давайте на китайцев/японцев/корейцев посмотрим? там уж точно 10ти летние пацаны игры для яФонов пишут и сайты ломают.. а времена точно не те.. посмотри те у каждого школьника на юбюте есть канал, где он так и блещет своим интеллектом и твитер со школьными проблемами

Comment: А еще лучше, пусть в футбол-хоккей после школы гоняет.

Comment: Уже гоняет да еще как...

Comment: Поддерживаю! Всестороннее развитие даст много больше плюсов. Также поможет определиться именно с той стезей, по которой парень реально захочет пойти.

Comment: Я написал: если сам не очень хочет. Если хочет заниматься программированием, если это его притягивает, то пусть занимается с какого получится возраста. Только все равно про общее образование и развитите не стоит забывать.

Comment: физкультуру никогда нельзя забывать.., хотябы выходить с ребенком бегать ) и не забывайте что отношение к миру, как его ребенок будет воспринимать формируется в детстве... если он будет видеть что бухают, курят он будет думать что так и надо делать.

Answer (score 11):

Лично я бы посоветовал капнуть в сторону логического мышления!

Давать интересные и простые задачи на логику.

Допустим:
Нужно поджарить котлету, а для этого нужно купить мясо в магазе, сделать фарш, зажечь газ на плите, поставить сковороду и т.д.

Такие задачи научат логически мыслить.

Далее, а лучше параллельно давать читать соответствующую литературу. Какой именно язык начать тут даже не могу подсказать, я столкнулся с бейсиком в 6м классе, примерно на полгода, потом в колледже 3года паскаля, потом был делфи года 1,5-2, потом пхп и прочие языки.

Раз хорошо владеет с компом, поставьте ему на какую-нить железяку Unix в нем его логика и проявится + начитается много инфы в нете по тому как что устанавливать на него. быть может и перейдет на программирование на С(#,++) и прочие версии С :)

Но логика в программирование, на мой взгляд, это самое главное, если этого нет, то ничего путного не получится. Посмотри сам на вопросы на форуме, кто их и как задает, и что за вопросы. Без логики ребята садятся программировать :)

у меня все

Comment: ;-)) По моему опыту главное - найти время и сесть рядом с ним. У меня та же проблема (сыну 11 лет). Пока со временем туго...

Comment: Честно, даже у меня не было бы времени после работы уделить время "Начинающему" да даже своему сыну, помочь ему программировать. Придя после работы, и начать еще раз раздирать задачи и напрягать мозг. Если только проверять и где-то подсказать.

Так что тут либо самообучение, либо отдать в колледж там его натаскают преподы. В питере могу подсказать такой. Там отличные преподы по програмимрованию и сетям.

Comment: @Shrek оболтус и так учится в оч. приличной школе там у него есть информатика, математика на приличном уровне. Ходит на олимпиады, побеждает и проч. Я хотел сверх того что ему дают в школе. По вечерам когда чего-то кодю постоянно подходит и спрашивает - оттуда и возникла мысль

Comment: @Barmaley ставь запятые в предложениях, я чуть не обиделся :) (первое самое слово) :)

Ну тогда давай ему задачки сам, напиши ему что-нибудь интересное.
Кстати было бы, я считаю неплохо, дать ему попробовать понять принцип создания структур БД - это логика на "ура"!

Answer (score 11):

*Disclaimer: ничего не понимаю в воспитаниях детей. Но в книжном шкафу у меня в детстве было чего почитать.*

Литературу в доступном месте держите, чтобы ее было видно. Немного, чтобы глаза не разбегались, но с разными подходами, чтобы если одна «не пойдет» всегда была альтернатива. Не стоит держать только примтивный уровень «бейсик для чайников за 21 день» — более фундаментальным вещам типа SICP тоже найдется место. По крайней мере, я, помнится, будучи младшей школотой, листал и достаточно «серьезный» научпоп — в силу отсутствия образования понималось все смутно и ограниченно, но читать это никак не мешало — интересно же было.

Заинтересуется — сам увидит, откроет, прочитает, попробует и так далее во все тяжкие. Не заинтересуется — как известно, насильно мил не будешь.

По крайней мере, мне никогда ничего не навязывали и даже, в общем-то, не предлагали. Отец собрал компьютер (ZX Spectrum 48k), показал в духе «смотри какую штуковину собрал!» и все. Сомневаюсь, что если бы мне навязывали с этим возиться, мне бы было это интересно.

Answer (score 8):

Про [Лого](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) все уже забыли? А язык, тем не менее, мощный. И мозги не калечит, как всякие бейсики-паскали.

Comment: Лого...........

Comment: @Asen Я заинтригован. Что могут означать одиннадцать точек?

Comment: И не лень было точки считать? Лучше бы занялись чем-нибудь полезным =)

Comment: Так ведь написал же, что заинтригован. А считать? `len('...........')` в питоне. copy-paste однако.

Comment: Достаточно было бы шести

Comment: @avp Ещё одна загадка

Comment: Почему загадка ? При начале ввода комментария справа пишется количество символов. В самом начале там написано число 10 и текст "символов нужно".

Comment: Увы мне! Позор на мои седины.

Comment: Или зажать клавишу на пару секунд :)

Comment: А за что Паскалю-то приложили?

Answer (score 6):

http://dl.gsu.by/
Много задач для разного уровня. Благодаря этим курсам и некоторому вмешательству преподавателей, школьники прекрасно усваивают материал. Смысл заключается в том, чтобы решать сотни легких задач и посложнее. Также в том, чтобы научиться самостоятельно работать.  В общем, ориентировано на большое количество практики.

Comment: Учусь в ВУЗе у преподавателя-администратора системы Долинского М. С. Человечище.

Answer (score 5):

Приучить к чему-то гиблое дело, если вы пробуете, а он не хочет, возможно его призвание в чем-то другом. Попробуйте разные виды спорта, музыкальное образование, может быть театральный кружок. Он сам определит, что ему нужно, но показать должны вы - потому что дети сами не часто пробуют, о существовании каких-то направлений они могут просто не знать, либо знать, но иметь мнение, что они не интересные

Comment: Не соглашусь - ребенок продукт воспитания, а не цветок который сам по себе вырастет красивым...

Comment: ну "продукт" это, наверное, слишком грубо сказано =/, но есть доля правды.  
ИМХО лучшее воспитание - косвенное, когда ты не говоришь ребенку, что ему делать и как надо это делать, а (вспоминаю фильм "Начало") приподносишь идею таким образом, чтобы она не выглядела насильственно навязанной. Чтобы ребенок занимался этим не потому, что ему сказали этим заниматься, а потому что ему это нравится и хочется. Тогда будет толк.

Comment: Поэтому если принять ребенка, как цветок, то в вашем понимании, воспитание это собственноручное вытягивание ствола растения. И в итоге получится ситуация, когда ему не понятно, зачем его вытягивали, если он хотел разрастаться вширь.    
А положительный результат будет только тогда, когда вы посадите семя и дадите условия для роста. И если этот цветок вырастит самостоятельно, под вашим присмотром, тогда он будет прекрасным.

Answer (score 5):

Не секрет, что в школе и университете наиболее хорошо усваиваются те предметы, преподаватели коих являются фанатами данной области и буквально заражают учеников интересом к данным предметам. В связи с этим, если Вы хотите, чтобы Ваш ребенок программировал,- рассказывайте ему побольше интересных моментов из Вашего опыта программирования доступным языком, чтобы он мог принимать участие в дискуссии.

Не маловажную роль играет так же тип восприятия ребенком информации. Есть тип людей, для которых звуки и речь являются самым доступным видом информации - аудиалы,- дискуссии на тему программирования вполне смогут их заинтересовать. Однако в процентном соотношении большинство - визуалы,- изображение воспринимается ими легче, и если Ваш ребенок относится к этому типу, его более заинтересует, если Вы сможете *показать* ему программирование, его результаты, отвечая на его вопросы - рисовать схемы и приводить визуальные примеры, которые можно представить (к примеру, обьяснять ТОЭ можно на примере воды, текущей по трубам).

Можно попробовать заинтересовать ребенка программируемыми игрушками, коих сейчас обширное количество по доступным ценам, к примеру [такими](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/975), - я подобный вариант брату покупала - заинтересуетесь не меньше ребенка и будете вдвоем с ним монстрика ваять :)

Answer (score 4):

Не стоит ему навязывать программирование. Если он сам спросил как это и что это, то другой вопрос.
Я учился так:

1. Почитал о общем устройстве компьютера.
2. Начал учить VB, не осилил. Спросил у знакомого компьютерщика что-нить совсем простое.
3. По его совету начал учить HTML это дало мне базовое понятие, что все надо представлять в голове.
4. Попытался учить JS. не осилил
5. нашел книжечку по C++ и стал тем, кто я есть(чайником как был так и остался, но хоть базовое представление имею).

Но опять же -- я учился по наитию. Меня лично никто не обучал. Я все искал С.А.М.

Comment: а может еще не стоит навязывать ребенку умение писать и читать? у технарей дети обычно технари рождаются и вырастают )

Answer (score 4):

Наткнулся недавно на такую статейку: [Learnable programming](http://worrydream.com/LearnableProgramming/)

Она меня очень заинтересовала своей наглядностью, я почти не читал, а просто смотрел, как люди просто передают алгоритмы визуально. Меня это сначала задело лишь на уровне реализации такого «ядра», которое может так просто представлять «расшифровку» кода. Обычно мне такое не по нраву, но здесь — понравилось.

Потом каким-то образом я попал на сайт khanacademy.org (в вашем случае будет интересен раздел https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/tutorials/programming-basics), где как оказалось, можно научиться очень-очень многому, что связано с основами инженерии. Этот ресурс отличается от других тем, что здесь самое главное — наглядность. Посмотрите на  «[карту знаний](https://www.khanacademy.org/exercisedashboard)».

Я нашел очень много того, что упустил/проспал/пропасовал на парах. Теперь-то я точно завистую и сам тоже подучусь :)

Answer (score 3):

Ребёнок не хочет - не учить. Всё равно толку будет ноль. Впрочем можно разве что только подтолкнуть: задается вопрос - "Хочешь сам сделать такую игру/сайт, только лучше" - иногда работает

Comment: Мне казалось, что программирование - это не то же, что сайты и игры. Может, это наследие прошлого... Главная проблема - найти доступные ребенку интересные задачи. На одной пузырьковой сортировке далеко не уедешь...

Answer (score 2):

ребенку нужно во всем давать возможность себя попробовать: и в футболе, и в танцах, и в творчестве, и в программировании....а там он сам вам подскажет, что ему больше нравиться и к чему у него склонности...нельзя навязывать детям то, что хочешь делать сам!!!

Comment: Боже, зачем говорить банальности? Вы хоть прочитали предыдущее обсуждение?  

Можно дать и другие советы: например, не заводить детей, если не знаешь, как их воспитывать.  

Человек задал конкретный вопрос, не надо подозревать егов том, что он глупее вас.

Comment: Если совсем грубо, то есть 2 точки зрения на воспитание ребенка:

1) Теория "ребенок цветок" - пусть делает что хочет, к чему у него есть склонности тем пусть и занимается

2) Теория "ребенок чистый лист бумаги" - ребенок вырастет тем кого из него воспитали.

Я придерживаюсь 2-й теории. Г-жа Булавина, очевидно, сторонник 1-й теории. Я прекрасно помню как в меня "вбивали" музыку, математику и физику, чуть позже финансы, еще чуть позже менеджмент. Получилось вроде неплохо :) - не жалуюсь. А те мои сверстники которые росли "как цветы" - не буду комментировать...

Comment: Минус. Из содержания вопроса не следует, что ТС навязывает ребенку программирование.

Comment: начнем по порядку:
предыдущие обсуждения я прочитала!
"не заводить детей, если не знаешь, как их воспитывать"- скорее это ваши мысли вслух,Neofit. 
Банальность!?-  да она началась с середины осуждения! и вообще, никакого подозрения автор этой темы в глупости НЕТ, опять таки - это ваши мысли вслух!

Comment: Barmaley, теория воспитания ребенка "ребенок как цветок" или же "ребенок-император" имеет возрастные ограничения:  до 5 лет обращаются с ребенком, «как с императором», с 5 до 15 лет – «как с рабом», а после 15 – «как с равным».В воспитании своего ребенка этой теории я не придерживаюсь,у меня скорее микс, я стараюсь дать ребенку максимум, что могу себе позволить и стараюсь не ограничивать ребенка в его познании окружающего (в разумных рамках, конечно), но то, что я уверена ему нужно,я не спрашиваю, а объясняю, что эта необходимо и это пригодиться в жизни.

Answer (score 2):

Моими первыми книгами по программированию были толстенные тома по Visual Basic. Я бы и сейчас продолжал им заниматься, но маловат он уже для меня, не расширяют его, заточен изначально под мелкие учебные программки. Потом были книги по html. Много книг. Все это было безумно интересно. Ходил на бесплатные компьютерные курсы. Затем начали изучать Pascal в физмат лицее в классе информатики. Вот там уже были сложные алгоритмы, но с ними тоже справлялся на ура. С тех пор много воды утекло, многое было опробовано, а сейчас остановился на C# из-за его сильной схожести с Pascal, который я отлично понимал. К слову, изучение С/С++ в университете было для меня самым неблагодарным делом, и это стало худшим моим опытом в программировании. Начинать надо с того, чтобы ребенок сам взял самое простое обучающее пособие, будь то фильм или брошюра, и досканально освоил его, чтобы уже не мог в этой области наступить на грабли, а дальше уже сам сможет ориентироваться.

Comment: @Alex9

       но маловат он уже для меня, не расширяют его, заточен изначально под мелкие учебные программки. 

Ежели мне не изменяет склероз, то Рацональная Рожа (Rational Rose) на VB и написана. Когда-то было культовое (среди ООПеров) приложение. И не маленькое.

Answer (score 2):

Вот в копилку [RoboMind](http://www.robomind.net/ru/) - программируем танчик, может помочь заинтересовать ребенка в программировании.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, подарите ему LEGO Mindstorms

Comment: Это супер идея!

Answer (score 2):

Я бы сказал так: если у Вашего ребёнка есть тяга к кодингу, то он вполне может разобраться сам! Не нужно навязывать ему это силой! По моему мнению, пусть лучше уж картоху на огороде копает.

Мне самому 14 (в принципе, это легко определить по моим тупым вопросам :) ), я очень ленив, но смог побороть лень и начал кодить под Android в июле этого года. В итоге имею кучу утилит собственного производства и одну популярную игру в топе гугл плея (название не скажу, ибо здесь сие творение *очень* не оценят). Я даже не заметил, как постепенно научился кодить (наверно благодаря ХэшКоду). Самое главное для меня при кодинге - **лучше хороший ум и соображалка, чем быстрая скорость печати** и принцип "расслабься, это надолго".

Answer (score 1):

Я в 6-7 лет определился кем хочу стать, конечно специальность я в то время не выбрал :), но уже конкретно отвечал на вопросы кем ты хочешь стать? - компьютерщиком :) В лет 10 я уже определился что буду писать прикладные программы. Учился писать код, бегал в компьютерные клубы, читал литературу и практиковался. Вскоре я понял, web это моё!) Сначала html&css, потом PHP&JavaScript. Сейчас мне 17 и на PHP пишу года 4 точно, помимо этого, иногда втыкаю в СИ.
Кстати, учился я в школе так себе - 3,4. Вечно сидел и мечтал на уроках, ну и времени не было учить что-то дома, приходил что-то вечно писал. Сколько себя помню, играл в пару игр и через пару дней удалял. Всегда казалось что игра - пустая трата времени.

Comment: А что Вы думаете о таких фреймворках, как Happstack, Snap, Yesod? (Сам-то я в веб-фреймворках практически не разбираюсь. К сожалению).

Comment: о существовании таких вообще не слышал)

Comment: Ссылки на них есть здесь: http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/

Вдогонку:

    -- Ты суслика видишь?
    -- Нет.
    -- И я -- нет. А он есть.

(там интересные бенчмарки)

Comment: @Алексей Скляр, просто интересно, а *что именно* Вы пишете. Для чего программы предназначены?

Почему-то кажется, что пишите "для души", а не "что вам хочется" за деньги.

Answer (score 1):

А не лучше отправить его на футбол/борьбу/танцы/ещё куда-нибудь?
Может не стоит в таком возрасте лишний раз портить ему зрение компом и забивать мозг технологиями, которые 3 раза поменяются до того, как он повзрослеет?

Comment: Имхо поздно для советов. Хотелось бы увидеть отчет автора о проделанной работе:)

Comment: Да, нафиг эти компы. Пусть ребенок идет в патриотический кружок, а в школе занимается физкультурой и учит ОБЖ с основами православной культуры. Вот такие в нашей стране как раз и нужны.

Comment: @Debasher, а Вы серьезно считаете что технологии меняются так быстро?

Можете назвать хоть две-три *действительно новые*, которые появились за **последние 10 лет?** (не то, чтобы поменялись, а просто появились)?

Comment: Я бы вообще своё дитя к этому делу не подпустил =\

Comment: физкультурой в любом случае должен заниматься ) ИМХО, перед компом с 6-7 лет, после 14 лет за компом минимум 3 часа в день сидел, после 18 сидел минимум 4 часа в день. Работаю за компом программистом, т.е. минимум 8 часов за компом. Сейчас зрение отличное 1, многие завидуют.

Comment: Граждане, вы точно уверены что лучше топикстартера(и родителя) знаете что лучше для его ребенка?

Answer (score 0):

Меня именно игры привели к этому.

Правда не уверен что современные компьютерные игры могут подтолкнуть к программированию.
Я начинал с `dendy`, `sega`.

1. Был компьютер клавиатура по моему российский, где можно было заставить появляться на экране Марио и двигаться в разных направлениях, с указанной скоростью.
2. Еще помнится была электрическая иностранная игрушка с пружинами, со всякими трансформаторами, схемами электрической цепи. И книжка где говорилось, что куда подключить чтобы создать звук самолета, что куда чтобы лампочки мигали в определенном порядке.

Comment: > Правда не уверен что современные компьютерные игры могут подтолкнуть к программированию

Могут. Меня подтолкнул Stalker.

Answer (score 0):

В 10 лет ещё рановато таким заниматься, но если есть бурное желание...

1. Научиться строить алгоритмы. Существует множество игр, где нужно написать ход событий.
2. Мне очень нравится у `Microsoft` есть книжка c# для школьников. Думаю C# очень прост в изучении и понимании, т.к. сам преподаю его старшеклассникам.

Answer (score 0):

Репетитора на дом можно пригласить...

Comment: А вы очень смешной человек...

Comment: А что смешного?

Comment: @manking Ничего. Это сарказм. Вы сами-то как представляете - репетитор по программированию? Он будет объяснять то, что можно прочитать в книжках по программированию? И за это еще и платить? И пользы на порядок меньше, чем если сам читаешь, вникаешь, никто не мешает вдумываться и блаблабла.. И как сказали выше, пока сам ребенок не захочет, зачем его учить?

Comment: 1) дети не будут сами читать сложную книжку. А книг комиксов по программированию на русском не встречал. (нарпимер как здесь http://omega-it.blogspot.ru/2009/03/blog-post.html)

2) Культура разработки может сразу быть заложена.(если препод адекватный)

3) Математике учат, и ничего.

4) Репетитор может сэкономить много человеко-месяцев, за 1 минуту объясняя то, что ребенок может месяцами искать или делать.

5) Ребенок может скрытно хотеть учится, но не знать об этом.

Comment: «Энциклопедия профессора Фортрана».  
Правда не по программированию, а в общем по компьютерам. У меня в детстве была такая :-)

Comment: Я начал интересоваться сайтами в 12 лет. Юкоз, все дела.. В 14 решил выучить HTML, CSS. С ним мне помог освоится друг. Обучение далось очень легко, потому что постоянно менял шаблоны на своем недосайте на юкоз и видел код. Потом PHP. Вот тут, как бы и кто мне не объяснял, пока я сам книгу не прочитал (некоторые разделы и по нескольку раз), я ничего не понимал. Так что я считаю, что программирование - это вещь, типа "я сам".

Comment: > дети не будут сами читать сложную книжку

Я наверное был ненормальным ребенком:) Лет в 10 мне например были интересны книги "ЭВМ своими руками", "Посвящение в радиоэлектронику", само собой книги по ZX Spectrum... Думаю на этом форуме я не один такой.