# С чего начать Java в школе?

Tags: java

Я начинающий учитель программирования и сейчас собралась группа умных детей желающих поучиться чему-то вне школьной программы. Выбрали Java (так получилось и это не изменить) И тут встал вопрос, хорошо, научимся писать в консоли. А что дальше? Апплеты как я поняла уже устарели и нигде не поддерживаются...

Так что же там писать то?

В общем нужно конкретное современное и *несложное* применение, ну и что бы и похвастаться можно было бы, детям это тоже очень важно :)

Возраст от 14 до 18 лет.

Хочу в ответе услышать конкретное название технологии Java применимой к данным условиям и примеры ее использования.

Comment: Писать что либо используя javafx (расписание школьное, электронный дневник). Но лучше конечно что нибудь с javaee, но это уже посложней

Comment: Что-нибудь визуальное + базы данных, простенькие 2д игры

Comment: Апплеты хоть и считаются устаревшей технологией, но вполне поддерживаются браузерами. Кроме того можно писать приложения с графическим интерфейсом, а не только консольные. Ну и сейчас самый тренд для Java - писать приложения для Android.

Comment: @МихаилКетов: JavaEE школьникам? Вы оптимист )

Comment: @NickVolynkin организация обучения, конечно, важная вещь - но все-таки оффтопик

Comment: @PashaPash: когда увижу, что ответ прочитан - удалю.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну вот сейчас набросаем ответы и снесем позже :)

Comment: Технологии антиотладки и расшифровки кода в рантайме, API виндовс. Пусть пишут удаляльшики загрузчика виндовс и рассылают их по пекабу. Базарю, это их увлечет сильнее 2д-игр.

Comment: @tutankhamun может проще в чат было перейти. снести что-то, на что есть ответы - [не так то просто](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/105133/)

Comment: @PashaPash Я видел, что есть возможность преобразовывать длинный список комментариев в чат, но вот как это сделать не пойму

Comment: Попробуйте начать с разбора конкретной бесплатной среды разработки, например, Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Нравиться мне это - давайте будем учить жаву, а потом "а что же с ней делать???". Но раз уж так и плана нет и нужно продолжать мучать Java, то предлагаю посмотреть на интересную книгу, написанную Яковом Файном - [Программирование на Java для детей, родителей, бабушек и дедушек](http://myflex.org/books/java4kids/java4kids.htm). Там есть много чего хорошего и позитивного и на базе этой книги можно написать рабочий план (собственно, что должен был сделать преподаватель в первую очередь).

Эта книга есть и в переводе на русский, но если дети хотят учить программирование, то лучше уже его учить на английском.

Comment: Вы не совсем поняли, они пришли ко мне и сказали что хотят программировать на java  и теперь мне надо самой разобраться для чего это им могло бы пригодиться. А план нормальных уроков у меня есть но там надо ориентироваться на программу, а она не совершенна :(

Comment: А вот в этом случае нужно сказать - либо мы делаем правильную программу,либо делаем по "несовершенной программе". Получите свободу действий и учите детей нормально.

Comment: Что бы сделать правильную программу, нужно в том числе и проанализировать востребованность технологий... Чем я тут и занимаюсь :) А ту программу я уже переделала, не волнуйтесь, повыкидывала кучу уроков которые тратятся на никому не нужные (в этом возрасте и с этим багажом) знания. Дело в том что основы я им даю на уроке, а на кружке хотелось бы что-то такое, может слегка показушное что-ли... Заинтересовать и вдолбить основы самообучения...

Comment: немного припоздал, но вдруг комуто еще понадобиться. показушное, мультипользовательское, с соревновательным аспектом, в то же время несложное и для разных уровней есть такий ресурс https://www.codingame.com/